# Google Map Markers from Local JSON Data

Tags: jquery, json, maps

Greets!  Is it possible to create a Google Map in IE from JSON data stored locally (no server)?  I had a solution working that used local KML data which worked in Firefox but not IE, apparently because of cross-domain problems.  Would JSON provide a better solution?

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is quite possible using Google Maps JavaScript API V3.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/

You can add Markers to the map using your JSON data for the attributes.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Markers